# Elasticsearch 5.0.1 java permission issue

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, automation, ansible

I have been trying to install and run [Elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch) 5.0.1 in a [docker container](https://docker.com) based on Centos 6.8. I am getting the following error:

```
[2016-11-23T10:01:40,696][INFO ][i.n.u.i.PlatformDependent] Your platform does not provide complete low-level API for accessing direct buffers reliably. Unless explicitly requested, heap buffer will always be preferred to avoid potential system unstability.
[2016-11-23T10:01:40,825][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService ] [bZesYxH] publish_address {172.17.0.147:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
[2016-11-23T10:01:40,830][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapCheck ] [bZesYxH] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: bootstrap checks failed
initial heap size [2109734912] not equal to maximum heap size [32210157568]; this can cause resize pauses and prevents mlockall from locking the entire heap
max number of threads [1024] for user [seceon] is too low, increase to at least [2048]
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[2016-11-23T10:01:40,836][INFO ][o.e.n.Node ] [bZesYxH] stopping ...
2016-11-23 10:01:40,837 pool-1-thread-1 ERROR Unable to unregister MBeans java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanServerPermission" "createMBeanServer")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:457)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(ManagementFactory.java:465)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.unregisterLoggerContext(Server.java:246)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.stop(LoggerContext.java:300)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext$1.run(LoggerContext.java:265)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry$RegisteredCancellable.run(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:102)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.run(DefaultShutdownCallbackRegistry.java:72)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone please help me to understand this error and how to fix it?

```
2016-11-23 10:01:40,837 pool-1-thread-1 ERROR Unable to unregister MBeans java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("javax.management.MBeanServerPermission" "createMBeanServer")
```

Comment: When are you getting the error? when trying to build the container? run the container? What does your dockerfile look like? Why don't you use ES official image?

Comment: I have made minor edits to improve the english; but this question could be much improved with some more background information, such as answers to Yaron Idan's request for clarification. Remember - this site encourages you to [edit] and re-edit your question to make it as clear, understandable and useful as possible.

Answer (score 0):

So as per the error, you got to increase the `vm.max_map_count` plus the `max number of threads`.

In order to increase `vm.max_map_count` type in the below command in your terminal as `root`:

> sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144

Source: [configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/setup-configuration.html)

In order to increase the `max number of threads`, you got to increase the [ulimit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/max-number-of-threads.html):

> This can be done by setting ulimit -u 2048 as root before starting
>   Elasticsearch, or by setting nproc to 2048 in
>   /etc/security/limits.conf.